# Passing Data fom jquery dialog and returning results on same dialog

Tags: php, jquery, sql, authentication

I am trying to build an employee break log. Basically, I want to have a jquery popup login form where the credentials will be authenticated. If successfully authenticated, the popup will close and will place the datetime on the cell where employee clicked. the cell will be uneditable after entries have been made.. my html table looks like below.

```
          break out       break in    lunch out.. so on
personA      X                 X        X
personB      X                 X        X
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery, you can make a popup window with open().

Create a form with radio buttons for the break out, break in, etc. and set the display to none. The open() function of Jquery will make it popup.

```
<form style="display:none" id="break_popup">
    Break in<input type"radio" name="breakin"/>
    <!-- The rest of your form -->
</form>
```

and after in the javascript code, you can call it like this : `$("#break_popup").open();`